# Ways to force a Windows process to update its configuration (re-read its Registry settings)

Tags: windows, winapi, process, scripting, autohotkey

Using AutoHotkey (Windows APIs), what ways are there to force a running process to take note of changed Registry settings, and re-read them **without restarting** that process?

I am trying to script [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com) which is famously unscriptable by choice (requests raised years ago, unaddressed).

Under Windows you could script some preferences without resorting to UI automation

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Michael Herf\flux\Preferences]
"fullscreendisable"=dword:00000001
```

... however unlike UI Automation this won't "take" unless the app is restarted (it doesn't monitor its Registry settings). A process restart would entail a flash of high color temperature light at night (FOHCTLAN) on the screens, something I'd like to avoid.

If there are ways to do this, I am interested in understanding the general approach to take with this problem (what APIs are available, how to investigate a particular app, then implement a script).

Thank you!

Comment: You can't *force* the application to do anything. If the app is written to be notified when things change (such as handling the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message in its message loop and refreshing its registry values, which is not required by any means), you're most likely out of luck. If the app is written only to read the config information when it's started, you can't change that behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! Guess I'll have to blank the screen during the restart :P

Comment: **A process restart would entail a flash of blue-colored light on the screens** Can you show a snapshot of the a flash of blue-colored light?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT You know, I was alluding to those web performance terms like FOUC (flash of unstyled content). If the screen is at 2700K and f.lux restarts you're blasted with 6500K light.

Comment: @Rita f.lux is an application that changes the color temperature of displays depending on the time of day. Exiting the process resets the display to its defaults.